# Is there a programatic way to determine if a font is scalable or non-scalable?

Tags: fonts, bitmap, scalable

I am trying to determine if a font is scalable or non-scalable and can't seem to find a good way to do this.

Does anyone know of a way to determine this on Windows?

Comment: What do you mean with "scalable"?

Comment: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/scalable_font.html

Comment: No, what do **you** mean with scalable. Except for EBDT data, which is virtually always used as fallback data, all glyph outlines in OpenType fonts are vector instructions, which are inherently infinitely scalable: if you have an OpenType font (ttf/otf/ttc) at all, the question "is it scalable?" is pretty much by definition "yes". So, are you asking "how can I tell if embedded bitmap data is being used by the shaper"? Or are you asking about some niche or obsolete font format? Or... (fill in details here, by updating the original question so that others can immediately see those details too)